# Trying to make an an array where the probability of each of its elements being 1 is 1/(abs(i-j)+2), otherwise zero

Tags: python, computer-science

So far I've done:

```
import numpy as np
import random

#helper function no. 1



def seed_probabilities(i,j):

    rand_num = random.random()
    x = 1/(abs(i - j) + 2)
    
    if rand_num < x:
        y = 1
    else:
        y = 0
    return y

def create_world(nr, nc):

#make array

    values = np.empty((nr,nc), dtype=int)


    #index array

    for i in range(0,nr):
        for j in range(0, nc):
            y = seed_probabilities(i,j)
            np.append(values, y)
    return values
```

```
create_world(6,7)
```

The output looks like this

```
array([[  4128860,   6029375,   3801155,   5242972,   7274610,   7471207,7143521],[  6357060,   6357108,   6357084,   6357102,   7274595,   6553710,3342433],[  4980828,   6422633,   7536732,   7602281,   2949221,   6357104,7012451],[  6750305,   7536741,   4784220,   7929936,   6815860,   7209071,6488156],[  7471215,   6029413,   7209065,   6619252,   6357106,   7602275,7733353],[  7536741,   6619240,   7077996,   7340078,       121, 538976288,538976288]])
```

but I need it to be ones and zeroes.

Basically, xr is the number of rows in the array and xc is the number of columns. The helper function seed_probabilities generates either zero or 1, with probabilities contingent on i and j, which are the indices of the array in question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean `y = seed_probabilities(i,j)`?  Because otherwise that should get a NameError because `y` is undefined.

Comment: Note that `return` is not a function. Also please [edit] your post to fix your code, because as posted this code cannot run.

Comment: `np.append`  is the root of the problem.  Numpy doesn't work that way.  Just do `values[i,j] = y` and all will be well.

Comment: You are appending into an uninitialized array which is giving you large and arbitrary values, not all of which were you overwriting

Answer (score 2):

You can do this entirely with `numpy` and save a lot of work:

```
# 1. Create an array of random values:
randvals = np.random.random((6,7))

# 2. Make an array of the probabilities based on index:
probabilities = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: 1/(abs(i-j)+2), randvals.shape)

# 3. Compare to compute the boolean True/False array:
result = randvals < probabilities

# 4. Optional: Convert to 0s and 1s:
result = result.astype(np.int8)
```

No need for any manual loops, no need for a separate `seed_probabilities` function, leaving `create_world` as just:

```
def create_world(nr, nc):
    randvals = np.random.random((nr,nc))
    # Adding np.vectorize isn't strictly necessary, but it dramatically improves performance for larger matrices
    probabilities = np.fromfunction(np.vectorize(lambda i, j: 1/(abs(i-j)+2)),
                                    randvals.shape)
    return (randvals < probabilities).astype(np.int8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two simple problems.  You were not assigning to `y`, and you were using the wrong API to build the array.  This works:

```
import numpy as np
import random

def seed_probabilities(i,j):
    rand_num = random.random()
    x = 1/(abs(i - j) + 2)
    return rand_num < x

def create_world(nr, nc):
    values = np.empty((nr,nc), dtype=int)
    for i in range(nr):
        for j in range(nc):
            values[i,j] = seed_probabilities(i,j)
    return values

print(create_world(6,7))
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 0]]
```